# Angular registering a callback in a child component that must return observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a autocomplete input component for selecting a contact from a list. If the autocomplete list has no results, an option is displayed to create a new contact. Clicking this option calls createContact() on my component. Now, many different types of contacts can be created in many different ways, but all contact models implement a "Contactable" interface so the autocomplete has the information to display the contacts correctly.

So my component doesnt know how to even start creating this new contact. I would like to provide the component with an `Observable<Contactable>` callback from the parent component that can be subscribed to by my autocomplete component. I've read that providing Observables as inputs is not recommended, so how else would I do this?

Here is a stackblitz example:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azjzwr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html)

Comment: It's not clear how many components are involved (*you say:* "*autocomplete input component*", "*my component*", "*the component*",  "*parent component*"); can you share some template code that shows the hierarchy of components?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally, you could drop the code into a online IDE like https://stackblitz.com 
and immediately someone can get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: Added stackblitz example

Comment: Is the datasource of contacts the same for all autocomplete lists in the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) annotation for this. Add an EventEmitter in your child component:

```
@Output() newContact = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

Emit an event in your child component when a contact is created:

```
createContact(event: Event): any {
  this.newContact.emit();
}
```

Add an event listener in your parent component:

```
<autocomplete-filter-example (newContact)="doSomething()"></autocomplete-filter-example>
```